# цепочка сертификатов выпущена центром сертификации не имеющим доверия

Tags: sql-server, ssl

Всем добрый день!

При попытке подключения источника данных в Excel(SQL-сервер) выпадает следующая ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Учетка пользователя на сервере и учетка база данных активна.
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема и куда копать.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/troubleshoot/sql/connect/error-message-when-you-connect